# Swift compiler doesn't show file & line of an error when the compiler crashed

Tags: xcode, swift, crash

Now the project I'm working on contains many files. I can hardly find the error point. How can I print the position? (I've upgraded to Xcode 6 Beta 7)

Following is my error message:

```
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %.asUnsubstituted = bitcast %CSo7UIColor* %78 to i64, !dbg !397
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta7.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Stupid question:  Do you know the difference between compiling and executing?

Comment: @HotLicks. I should repeat: THE COMPILER CRASHED! Not my app.

Comment: So how do you know?  What messages did it produce?

Comment: @HotLicks: It's a common issue of swiftc, and it will be little different in various situation. My hint is: Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither %.asUnsubstituted = bitcast %CSo7UIColor* %78 to i64, !dbg !397 LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!

Comment: @HotLicks: And the compiler exits with code 1.

Comment: If you Google "LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!" you will find this is a compiler bug.  Several different scenarios have been identified, so if you look at several "hits" you may recognize the scenario causing your troubles and find a circumvention.  Or you can simply wait for Swift to stabilize.

Comment: @HotLicks: I know it's a compiler bug, so I'm trying to avoid it, and so I'm trying to find the error point... Do you have any idea?

Comment: Wait for Swift to stabilize.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimisations turned on? I've got a vague recollection of a compiler crash with bitcasts when compiling for release... (Also: have you filed this bug with Apple yet?)

Comment: @MattGibson: The project is compiled in debug mode, so no optimisation flags I think. I didn't report the bug because I am not able to locate the error. Anyway I can't upload the whole project.

Comment: @MattGibson: I don't think Apple can release the stable version of swiftc on Sep.9.

Comment: @Msr.B Well, it's already stable enough for me; I guess it depends on how many bugs they see coming in, which was one of the reasons I'd asked you if you'd reported it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error as well after upgrading to beta 7. The line that cause the error for me was
`myUIButton.setTitleColor(.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)`

and the fix was

`myUIButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)`

Hopefully this is your case as well.